# pgf-Tikz QR code generator

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, pst-barcode, barcodes

> **This question led to a new package:**
> [`qrcode`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/qrcode)

I am looking for a `Tikz` QR code generator. I am aware of `pst-barcode` as well as several "local" programs, a luatex solution and web services to do this. Nevertheless, if at all possible, I would much prefer a `Tikz` replacement working with `pdflatex/xelatex` as well, since this is the most common baseline at the moment. If this doesn't yet exist, I would be willing to award a bounty on the creation of one. However I will wait until someone expresses interest in doing so, since I am not sure how long this might take.

This [link](http://qrcodenet.codeplex.com/) contains a couple of links to the spec and possibly helpful implementations.

Comment: [related](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88599/4785)

Comment: TikZ won’t be the problem here. Only the translation of text to its binary representation (which is then visualized in two dimensions) is probably a little trickier, but solely a TeX programming problem.

Comment: ... and yet another package will see the light of screens all across the LaTeX world! `:)`

Comment: I was actually thinking about a QR package written solely in LaTeX (and displayed with TikZ), but minded the effort of the coding implementation so far. Maybe I find time after all for it.

Comment: A range of language implementations is provided [here](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is a new package on CTAN:

> Anders O.F. Hendrickson submitted the
>
> ```
>             qrcode
> ```
>
> package.
>
> Version number: 1.0 License type: lppl1.3
>
> Summary description: Generate QR codes in LaTeX.
>
> ### Announcement text:
>
> This package generates Quick Response (QR) codes in LaTeX, without the
>   need for pstricks or any other graphics package.
>
> ---
>
> This package is located at
>   http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/qrcode
>
> More information is at    http://www.ctan.org/pkg/qrcode

I installed the package via TeXLive 2014 and the result looks correct with pdfLaTeX, xeLaTeX and luaLaTeX.

Code example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{qrcode}
\begin{document}
\qrcode[]{Dummy code}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: QRCODE example]

Answer (score 35):

Well this is cheating, but I could not resist:

## The result

[image: Result]

## The document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{qrcode}
% Defines \qrcode command to be used inside a tikzpicture, with two arguments
%  #1  Size of the square (in tikz relative units) [optional, defaults to 10 units]
%  #2  String for the QRCode
% It draws the qrcode using styles "pixel on" and "pixel off" and defines
% a node named (qrcode) of the given size, so you can refer to its anchors for
% further drawing or labelling.

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2mm]
  \qrcode[4]{This is a test};
  \node[below=of qrcode] {This is a test};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\hfill
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2mm]
\qrcode[6]{https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102569/12571}
\node[below=of qrcode] {This is not an answer};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## The cheat

### Contents of `qrcode.sty`

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\directlua{dofile("luaqrcode.lua")}  % <--- Oooh!
\newcommand{\qrcode}[2][10]{%
\begin{scope}[qrcode]
\directlua{tikzQRCode("#2",#1)}%
\end{scope}
}
\tikzset{
  qrcode/.style = {line width = 2sp},
  pixel on/.style = {black},
  pixel off/.style = {white},
  pixel err/.style = {red}
}
```

### Contents of `luaqrcode.lua`

```lua
qrencode = dofile("qrencode.lua")    --  <--- Ooooh! You cheater!

local function matrix_to_tikz( tab , size)
  if (size == nil) then size=10 end
  pixel_width = size / #tab
  pixel_cmd = string.format("\\filldraw[%%s] (%%f, %%f) +(-%f, %f) rectangle +(%f, -%f);",
          pixel_width/2, pixel_width/2, pixel_width/2, pixel_width/2)
  str_tab = {}
  for y=1,#tab do
    row = {}
    for x=1,#tab do
      if tab[x][y] > 0 then
          style = "pixel on"
      elseif tab[x][y] < 0 then
          style = "pixel off"
      else
          style = "pixel err"
      end
      if style=="pixel off" then
          row[x] = ""
      else
          row[x] = string.format(pixel_cmd, style, x*pixel_width, -y*pixel_width)
      end
    end
    str_tab[y] = table.concat(row, "\n")
  end
  local extra = {}
  extra[1] = string.format("\\coordinate (aux1) at (%f,-%f);", pixel_width/2, size+pixel_width/2)
  extra[2] = string.format("\\coordinate (aux2) at (%f, %f);", size+pixel_width/2, -pixel_width/2)
  extra[3] = "\\node[inner sep=0pt, fit=(aux1) (aux2)] (qrcode) {};"
  str_tab[#tab+1] =  table.concat(extra, "\n")
  return table.concat(str_tab,"\n")
end

function tikzQRCode(txt, size)
    local ok, tab_or_message = qrencode.qrcode(txt)
    if not ok then
        tex.print(tab_or_message)
    else
        tex.print(matrix_to_tikz(tab_or_message, size))
    end
end
```

### The file `qrencode.lua`

It can be downloaded from here:

[image: luaqrencode]

## Update: A note on performance

The compilation of the main document took more time than I expected (a few seconds) but the bottleneck is not Lua, but tikz. The lua code generates a lot of small rectangles to be filled, and tikz requires time to draw all of them (I replaced the tikz-generation code in lua for simple "print" statements to the console, and it compiled almost instantaneously).

Trying to reduce the compile-time, I modified the lua code so that only the black pixels are actually drawn, thus reducing the compile time to the half (in my first implementation Lua generated both the black and the white pixels).

The compiling time can be dramatically improved if, instead of using tikz to draw the pixels, tex `\rule` primitive is used, as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88599/create-bitmap-within-tex-file/88610#88610) which basically does the same thing than my code, but without tikz (thanks to michal.h21 for pointing me to his answer).

Inspection of library `luaqrcode` shows that the QR algorithmm is rather complex. Although a lot of values are precomputed and stored in tables, which would simplify a pure tex implementation, I'm concerned for the performance of that implementation.

Comment: The last link is [http://speedata.github.com/luaqrcode/](http://speedata.github.com/luaqrcode/).

Comment: @PaulGaborit Sorry for the little prank, but I had made the image clickable :-)

Comment: @JLDiaz for solution using `\vrule` see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88610/2891

Comment: @michal.h21 Thanks! Obviously I was not aware of your implementation, otherwise I woulnd't do mine... This is probably the "luatex solution" that the OP mentions in his question.

Comment: Github stopped providing developer subdomains on 2021-04-15.  luaqrcode can be found here: https://github.com/speedata/luaqrcode