# Problem creating a proper qrcode with vcard info

Tags: pdftex, barcodes

I have this little latex file generating a qr-code using Hendrickson's qrcode.sty found here: [pgf-Tikz QR code generator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89649/pgf-tikz-qr-code-generator/203487#203487).

```
\documentclass[english,11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\begin{document}
\qrcode{
BEGIN:VCARD^^J
VERSION:4.0^^J
N:Doe;John^^J
TEL;WORK:+1 (234) 567-8910^^J
EMAIL:john@doe.com^^J
END:VCARD
}
\end{document}
```

It generates indeed the following qr-code but when i scan it with my phone, I get no information.

[image: QR-code with non info.]

How should I do it?

Regards,
F.

Comment: Try removing trailing ^^J from the vcard code.

Comment: No, doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your vcard format, not with the generated qrcode nor with latex.

Comment: I cannot find fault with your vcard block. May have to specify QRCode version. I had to when the URLs were too long for v.4 which was default. Yours seem to be v.5 though.

Answer (score 3):

Even after you remove the trailing `^^J`, it won't work quite the way you wanted, as others have noted.  After some experimenting, I found that removing all regular newlines and adding `\?` (which is qrcode's marker for "newline") does the trick:

`\qrcode{BEGIN:VCARD\?VERSION:4.0\?N:Doe;John\?TEL;TYPE=work:+1(234)567-8910\?EMAIL:john@doe.com\?END:VCARD}`

(with no linebreak) works exactly the way you want, at least when I check it with my phone.  Here's what it looks like:

[image: John Doe vcard, via \qrcode]

Answer (score 1):

The 2 qrcode generated here are not the same and the first doesn't give any info. The second does for me. So you see, same vcard format.

```
\documentclass[english,11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

{\obeylines\gdef^^M{^^J}%
 \catcode`\@=0 %
 \catcode`\\=12 %
 @gdef@n{\n}}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % uncomment this if used with pdflatex

\begin{document}

\qrcode{
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
N:Doe;John
TEL;TYPE=work:+1(234)567-8910
EMAIL:john@doe.com
END:VCARD
}

\medskip
\begin{pspicture}(1in,1in)
\obeylines
\psbarcode{%
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
N:Doe;John
TEL;TYPE=work:+1(234)567-8910
EMAIL:john@doe.com
END:VCARD
}{width=1. height=1.}{qrcode}%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess the qrcodes do not work the same in package qrcode or pst-barcode.

Answer (score 0):

Rin with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(1in,1in)
\psbarcode{%
        BEGIN:VCARD^^J
        VERSION:4.0^^J
        N:Doe;John^^J
        TEL;WORK:+1 (234) 567-8910^^J
        EMAIL:john@doe.com^^J
        END:VCARD
    }{encoding=raw}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is not a latex issue, the format of your vcard is wrong.

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[english,11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\begin{document}
\qrcode{
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
N:Doe;John;;;
TEL;TYPE=work:+1 (234) 567-8910
EMAIL:john@doe.com
END:VCARD
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, you did not solve the problem. Still no info after the scan.

Comment: As I said, this is not a latex problem, since the qrcode is rendered properly. Maybe your phone is not compatible with this version of vcard?

Comment: I don't have problem scanning the same info generated with pst-barcode.